# Use TOTP as client_secret with OAuth

Tags: oauth2, totp

Can we use 10 digital TOTP as client_secret? What security problems would this do, and maybe some benefits? After all, TOTP changes every 30 seconds, but you need to know e.g. a 32 byte secret (which will never be sent across any request) to compute it. Is it a good idea?

Comment: It's technically possible and secure.

Comment: I read this article: https://pulsesecurity.co.nz/articles/totp-bruting and I think this is not a good idea. After a few wrong attempts to guess TOTP, you would have to block the client for a while, which is a very bad solution.

Comment: If the client_secret is found to be wrong, the entire authorization process is repeated which consumes enough time that brute force attack will be very slow.

Comment: Hm, it's true. However, be aware that the authorization server will need to store a different symmetric key in order to encrypt the TOTP secrets stored for clients. This problem doesn't occur when using base client_secret as we only store its hash.